# Displaying cultures in combo box and selecting

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to display cultures in the combox box and I want the user to receive the DisplayName of the culture when selected but I get culture code ie 'en', 'ar' etc

The itemsource of the combo box is

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SupportedCultures, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Language}" SelectedValue="DisplayName" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
```

SupportedCultures property

```
public static List<CultureInfo> SupportedCultures
{
    get 
    { 
        return _SupportedCultures; 
    }
}
```

How can I get DisplayName in my selectedItem's Language property which is of type string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedItem` requires the same kind of object that your `ItemsSource` is bound to, so don't use that. If you want to select by the value of a property, then use `SelectedValue`, and to tell WPF which property to check for that value, use `SelectedValuePath`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SupportedCultures, Mode=OneWay}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Language}" 
SelectedValuePath="DisplayName" 
DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. Your List is static. So, to bind to it, you should use {x:Static} source:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static yournamespace:YourClassName}, Path=SupportedCultures, Mode=OneWay}" 
DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
```

Note that SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Language}" binds your selected CultureInfo to your ComboBox's DataContext. So, in this case a DataContext of your ComboBox should have object SelectedItem with CultureInfo Language {get;set;} property. I don't think that's what you are looking for?)

Comment: SelectedItem is my datacontext and had a property of Language.